# Unable to apply different fill style to two canvas rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Why am I not able to add two different styles to two Rectangles `ctx` and `ctx2` in the following code?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.fill();


var ctx2 = c.getContext("2d");
ctx2.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx2.rect(60, 120, 150, 100);
ctx2.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: You mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/9kx8g58v/

Comment: so do I have to use `beginPath()` instead of rect?

Comment: Yes, you always need to use `beginPath` in order to switch context.

Comment: got it thanks a lots

Comment: Glad to help, pal!